# C++ Move Constructor With Pointers (*&& Syntax)

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, reference

I would like to know if there are any problems with the construction `<type>*&&` in C++. Let me give a concrete example.

Say we have a class that should be constructed from an array. We would usually do something like this:

```
class Things 
{

    public:
         Things(const ThingType* arrayOfThings, int sizeOfArray) 
            : myArray(new ThingType[sizeOfArray])
         {
              for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
                  myArray[i] = arrayOfThings[i]; 

         }

    private:
         ThingType* myArray;
  }
```

This is fine if we want to preserve `arrayOfThings`, because we are doing a deep copy of it. Moreover, by using `const` we are ensuring it won't be modified inside the constructor.

But suppose our program has a lot of statements like this one:

```
Things myThings(new ThingType[9001] {thing_0, ... , thing_9000}, 9001);
```

This might seem weird, but it may happen that the huge `ThingType` array is returned from a function as a rvalue.

In that case, we don't care about preserving the pointer passed as a parameter. In fact, we definitely **don't** want to do a deep copy of it, because it would be a huge waste of time preserving something we are about to destroy anyways.

One possible solution to this would to add another constructor that would handle the case of a non-const rvalue `ThingType` pointer, like a general move constructor handles the case of a non-const rvalue instance of the class:

```
public:
     Things(ThingType*&& arrayOfThings, int sizeOfArray) 
            : myArray(arrayOfThings)
         {
              arrayOfThings = NULL;                  
         }
```

This seems to be solving the problem for me, but I did not find much information about the `<type>*&&` construction seen above. Is it kosher, or will I be sent to the dungeons for mixing pointers and references?

Comment: This is not recommended. For example: `ThingType* t = new ThingType{ ... }; Thing myThing(&t, ...);` will call the `ThingType*&&` overload

Comment: The recommended way would be to stop using raw arrays and move  to `std::vector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I believe I found satisfactory - although far from optimal - solutions. Since no one answered the question, I will share the best workarounds I found.

As Justin pointed out, using `ThingType*&&` can lead to trouble when we take the address of a variable of `ThingType` (but not of a `ThingType` pointer, as he implied in his answer) in the constructor call.

If `t` is a `ThingType`, the expression `&t` is an r-value of type `ThingType*`, so `Thing myThing(&t, ...)` will call the move constructor, with the result of making `myThing.myArray` point to `t`. This is not what we would want in most cases.

One solution is to use vectors instead of arrays, as illustrated below:

```
// Copy
explicit Things(const std::vector<ThingType>& vectorOfThings) 
            : myVector(vectorOfThings)
         {  }

// Move
explicit Things(std::vector<ThingType>&& vectorOfThings) 
        : myVector(std::move(vectorOfThings))
         {  }
```

The move constructor would then be used in situations like this:

`Things myThings(vector<ThingType>{thing_0, ... , thing_9000});`

Although this solves the problem, it is not feasible if we are dependent on an API which returns raw pointers, or if we want don't want to give up arrays. In this case, we can use smart pointers to solve the problem.

Suppose, we have a function `ThingType* generateArray()` which we want to use to initialize our object of type `Things`. The first thing we should do is to wrap this function with another function that returns a smart pointer instead.

```
unique_ptr<ThingType[]> generateSmartPointer()
{
  return unique_ptr<ThingType[]>(generateArray());
}
```

Here I used a `unique_pointer`, but this could change depending on the implementation.

Now we add a new constructor to `Things`, with a instance of `unique_ptr` as an argument. This will act as the move constructor for arrays of `ThingType`:

```
Things(unique_ptr<ThingType[]> thingsPointer, int sizeOfArray) 
        : myArray(thingsInput.release()), size(sizeOfArray)
         {  }
```

`unique_ptr<T>.release()` is used to get the array, and at the same time make the unique pointer release ownership of it, preventing the array from being deleted once the unique pointer is destroyed.

And that's it. These are the two best solutions I found to this problem, and while they are far from perfect, they have worked so far considering the objectives for each implementation.

Comment: `explicit Things(ThingType * things, int count) : myVector(things, things + count) {}` if you need to construct from a `ThingType *, int` pair, or `template <int N> explicit Things(ThingType(&things)[N]) : myVector(things, things + N) {}` initialise `vector` from a raw array